# Recoding variables with a pattern in R

Tags: r, stata

I am a stata user learning R. 
I want to translate the following stata function to R. Basically what it does is to recode several variable with names with a pattern with a loop function.

i have these variables names: `a1cbf a2cbf a3cbf a4cbf ....... a25cbf`

Stata syntax:

```
forvalue i=1/25{
  recode a`i'cbf (1=99) (2=88) (3=1), gen(cig`i')
}
```

This is what it means in words : loop the following command each time replacing `i' with value from 1 to 25.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to replace the numbers in the variable with a vector of different numbers.

If 'v1' is the vector of original variables

```
 v1 <- paste0('a', 1:25, 'cbf')
```

and the new vector of numbers corresponding to the 'v1' elements is

```
set.seed(29)
v2 <- sample(100, 25, replace=FALSE)
```

We can use `paste` to get a new vector of variables that can be later assigned to the column names/row names of the dataset.

```
paste0('a', v2, 'cbf')
```

Or if the prefix and suffix parts are not the same, then,

```
paste0(sub('[0-9]+.*', '', v1), v2, sub('.*[0-9]+', '', v1))
#[1] "a10cbf" "a24cbf" "a11cbf" "a32cbf" "a57cbf" "a9cbf"  "a78cbf" "a81cbf"
#[9] "a12cbf" "a22cbf" "a89cbf" "a35cbf" "a27cbf" "a55cbf" "a16cbf" "a71cbf"
#[17]"a56cbf" "a31cbf" "a72cbf" "a30cbf" "a54cbf" "a49cbf" "a76cbf" "a94cbf"
#[25] "a48cbf"
```